# Application getting crashed after excluding Firebase messaging

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobilepush

Initially I faced problem of duplicacy for firebase messaging files. I already posted this question here is the link [Firebase gives error of duplicacy for marketing cloud sdk](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/357505/firebase-gives-error-for-duplicate-classes-with-marketing-cloud-sdk). To solve this I exclude firebase messsaging. Which leads to crash my application. Code for excluding is

```
 implementation ('com.salesforce.marketingcloud:marketingcloudsdk:7.4.2',{
        exclude group: 'com.google.firebase', module: 'firebase-messaging'
    })
```

And gives me error of "An error occurred while executing doInBackground()". Also attaching error screenshot.[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can exclude the version from our SDK, but you must add a version of Firebase yourself -- which draws into question the root of the original error :). The Push SDK depends on FCM.

Show the output from your `./gradlew app:dependencies` to determine whether or not the necessary messaging dependencies are getting included.

The SDK is built with `firebase-messaging` version 22, but it can be downgraded to version 20.3.0 (ref. https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android#messaging_v20-3-0), however, you should test your implementation extensively as this has not been expressly tested by our team.

```
    implementation('com.salesforce.marketingcloud:marketingcloudsdk:7.4.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.google.firebase', module: 'firebase-messaging'
    })

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.3.0'
```

Comment: I already added Firebase dependencies like: implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.2.0', implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.1.0', implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.7', implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.4.2',  implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics:17.0.0', implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-perf:20.0.1'

Comment: The SDK requires firebase-messaging version 20.3.0 or greater.